# data compression - machine learning for exponential distribution

Tags: algorithm, compression, machine-learning, information-theory, exponential

Are there any machine learning algorithms, prediction models that can help me compress exponentially distributed data? I have already encoded the file using golomb codes, which definitely saves tons of space, but this is not enough -- I need compression. PAQ8L does not compress it enough.

Please ask for the file if needed.

Exponentially distributed --

{a,b,b,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,b,a,a,b,a,c,b,a,b,d}

Comment: A variant of Huffmann-coding maybe?

Comment: "PAQ8L does not compress it enough." What are your expectations ? What is the size of the data and what kind of compression ratio is "enough" ? Your expectations may be too high as "unreachable". Maybe you could try cmix though (you need a lot of memory): http://www.byronknoll.com/cmix.html.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's theoretically possible. The [Golomb code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding) is already optimal for geometrically distributed data.

Comment: Not true; google paq8l; it compresses the golomb coded string I am interested by at least 50%. Yes, it is definitely possible.

Comment: As mentioned in other posts, PAQ* algorithms use a context mixing algorithm. This means, you know more about data than just "exponentially distributed". @user562688

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other posts, PAQ* algorithms use a context mixing algorithm. This means, you know more about data than just "exponentially distributed". 
I think the Golomb code is still optimal if only the exponential distribution is known about the data.